# Java Regex: I wish to return value from double quotes in java, using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to return a String value located in double quotes, in java for instance 
"Home Lone". I am writing a test script to match whats on my UI and that in database. 
here is sample code

```
    public String getMonitorKeywords(String keywords1, String keywords2, String keywords3) {
    String words = "";
    if (keywords2 != null && keywords1 == null && keywords3 == null) {
        return words = keywords2.replaceAll("\\s+", " AND ");
        }

    else if(keywords2 == null && keywords1 == null && keywords3 != null){
        keywords2 = keywords3.replaceAll("\\s+", " OR ");
        words = keywords3;
        Util.println("From databse we have third keywords{}: " + words);
        return words;
    }

    else if(keywords2 != null && keywords1 != null && keywords3 == null){
        words = keywords1;
        Util.println("From databse we have first keywords{}: " + words);
        return words;
    }

    else if(keywords2 == null && keywords1 != null && keywords3 == null){
        words = keywords1;
        return words;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Problem with my method, when keywords2 has words with double quotes {""}, it increments AND into it which i dont want for those particular sets of words. Thanks i know its to do with regex expression to filter out such words with quotes. not all words have quotes.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `if` block access the "keyword" which is `!= null` rather than one that is?

Comment: Still need help on how to return value inside quotes

Comment: You can use a Matcher to do this with a pattern like `"(.*?)"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't get it...

```
"foo \"bar\" or something else".replaceAll("\\s+", " AND ")
```

produces

> foo AND "bar" AND or AND something AND else

Is that not your intention?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
("[^"]+?")|(\w+?)\b
```

and replace with `"$1$2 AND"`.

This will leave an extra " AND" at the end of the result, so you'll need to trim that off.